# Debugging IPSEC log

Tags: ipsec, openswan, fortinet, fortigate

A Fortigate unit and a Openswan based Linux server.
Tunnel is up but no data goes through.

This is the log from the Forti unit:

```
Line 204: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:19809969: responder received first quick-mode message
    Line 205: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: dec 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
    Line 206: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:19809969: peer proposal is: peer:0:192.168.43.88-192.168.43.95:0, me:0:62.219.16.0-62.219.16.255:0
    Line 207: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: trying
    Line 207: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: trying
    Line 208: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: matched phase2
    Line 208: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: matched phase2
    Line 209: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: autokey
    Line 209: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: autokey
    Line 210: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: my proposal:
    Line 210: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: my proposal:
    Line 211: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: proposal id = 1:
    Line 211: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: proposal id = 1:
    Line 212: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 212: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 213: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 213: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 214: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 214: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 215: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 215: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 216: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 216: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 217: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: incoming proposal:
    Line 217: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: incoming proposal:
    Line 218: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: proposal id = 0:
    Line 218: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: proposal id = 0:
    Line 219: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 219: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 220: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 220: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 221: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 221: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 222: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 222: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 223: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 223: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 224: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: negotiation result
    Line 224: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: negotiation result
    Line 225: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: proposal id = 0:
    Line 225: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: proposal id = 0:
    Line 226: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 226: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 227: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 227: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 228: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 228: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 229: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 229: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 230: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 230: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 231: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: set pfs=1024
    Line 231: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: set pfs=1024
    Line 232: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: using tunnel mode.
    Line 232: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: using tunnel mode.
    Line 233: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: enc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
    Line 234: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: out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
    Line 235: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: sent IKE msg (quick_r1send): XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:500->YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:500, len=292, id=134c9f806d9d835f/e1de0bffc846b57b:985cc310
    Line 239: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: dec 134C9F806D9D835FE1DE0BFFC846B57B08102001985CC31000000034000000142DD303A5E543AEE77C2E08F8A73023AB00000000
    Line 240: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: SA life soft seconds=1778.
    Line 240: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: SA life soft seconds=1778.
    Line 241: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: SA life hard seconds=1800.
    Line 241: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: SA life hard seconds=1800.
    Line 242: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: IPsec SA selectors #src=1 #dst=1
    Line 242: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: IPsec SA selectors #src=1 #dst=1
    Line 243: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: src 0 7 0:62.219.16.0-62.219.16.255:0
    Line 243: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: src 0 7 0:62.219.16.0-62.219.16.255:0
    Line 244: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: dst 0 7 0:192.168.43.88-192.168.43.95:0
    Line 244: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: dst 0 7 0:192.168.43.88-192.168.43.95:0
    Line 245: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: add IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0640/5c4f46c0
    Line 245: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: add IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0640/5c4f46c0
    Line 246: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: IPsec SA dec spi 774e0640 key 16:5922E5CC41401673A4081CCC9DDCDF1E auth 20:736B20618DF6F256A8BEE3DAE93EAE73C43A0D59
    Line 246: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: IPsec SA dec spi 774e0640 key 16:5922E5CC41401673A4081CCC9DDCDF1E auth 20:736B20618DF6F256A8BEE3DAE93EAE73C43A0D59
    Line 247: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: IPsec SA enc spi 5c4f46c0 key 16:2B14564A7C78E41AB5158DD30FCE2704 auth 20:37C815223871B6D63658DEF4AD7C10F1EEC110EA
    Line 247: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: IPsec SA enc spi 5c4f46c0 key 16:2B14564A7C78E41AB5158DD30FCE2704 auth 20:37C815223871B6D63658DEF4AD7C10F1EEC110EA
    Line 248: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: added IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0640/5c4f46c0
    Line 248: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19809969: added IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0640/5c4f46c0
    Line 824: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: dec 134C9F806D9D835FE1DE0BFFC846B57B08100501E443AEFC000000440C000014BA084B36F4FD8561304C6B8FD639079E000000100000000103040001E074C77800000000
    Line 825: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: recv IPsec SA delete, spi count 1
    Line 826: ike 0:Brazil_VPN: deleting IPsec SA with SPI e074c778
    Line 827: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:Brazil_ph2: deleted IPsec SA with SPI e074c778, SA count: 2
    Line 827: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:Brazil_ph2: deleted IPsec SA with SPI e074c778, SA count: 2
    Line 1482: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:19810263: responder received first quick-mode message
    Line 1483: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: dec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
    Line 1484: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:19810263: peer proposal is: peer:0:192.168.43.88-192.168.43.95:0, me:0:62.219.16.0-62.219.16.255:0
    Line 1485: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: trying
    Line 1485: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: trying
    Line 1486: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: matched phase2
    Line 1486: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: matched phase2
    Line 1487: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: autokey
    Line 1487: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: autokey
    Line 1488: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: my proposal:
    Line 1488: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: my proposal:
    Line 1489: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: proposal id = 1:
    Line 1489: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: proposal id = 1:
    Line 1490: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 1490: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 1491: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 1491: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 1492: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 1492: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 1493: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 1493: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 1494: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 1494: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 1495: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: incoming proposal:
    Line 1495: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: incoming proposal:
    Line 1496: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: proposal id = 0:
    Line 1496: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: proposal id = 0:
    Line 1497: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 1497: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 1498: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 1498: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 1499: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 1499: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 1500: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 1500: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 1501: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 1501: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 1502: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: negotiation result
    Line 1502: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: negotiation result
    Line 1503: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: proposal id = 0:
    Line 1503: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: proposal id = 0:
    Line 1504: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 1504: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   protocol id = IPSEC_ESP:
    Line 1505: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 1505: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:   PFS DH group = 2
    Line 1506: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 1506: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      trans_id = ESP_AES (key_len = 128)
    Line 1507: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 1507: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:      encapsulation = ENCAPSULATION_MODE_TUNNEL
    Line 1508: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 1508: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263:         type = AUTH_ALG, val=SHA1
    Line 1509: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: set pfs=1024
    Line 1509: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: set pfs=1024
    Line 1510: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: using tunnel mode.
    Line 1510: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: using tunnel mode.
    Line 1511: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: enc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
    Line 1512: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: out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
    Line 1513: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: sent IKE msg (quick_r1send): XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:500->YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:500, len=292, id=134c9f806d9d835f/e1de0bffc846b57b:ddbb8346
    Line 1517: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378: dec 134C9F806D9D835FE1DE0BFFC846B57B08102001DDBB8346000000340000001488D36AC062D8A15BFAF6869C6B02A74C00000000
    Line 1518: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: SA life soft seconds=1773.
    Line 1518: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: SA life soft seconds=1773.
    Line 1519: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: SA life hard seconds=1800.
    Line 1519: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: SA life hard seconds=1800.
    Line 1520: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: IPsec SA selectors #src=1 #dst=1
    Line 1520: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: IPsec SA selectors #src=1 #dst=1
    Line 1521: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: src 0 7 0:62.219.16.0-62.219.16.255:0
    Line 1521: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: src 0 7 0:62.219.16.0-62.219.16.255:0
    Line 1522: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: dst 0 7 0:192.168.43.88-192.168.43.95:0
    Line 1522: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: dst 0 7 0:192.168.43.88-192.168.43.95:0
    Line 1523: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: add IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0645/e1bb6929
    Line 1523: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: add IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0645/e1bb6929
    Line 1524: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: IPsec SA dec spi 774e0645 key 16:DAC0A7B14F20741D20112FA78EFB607A auth 20:17D48DCACA549180D9D88F6F1A491AD35F26A8D4
    Line 1524: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: IPsec SA dec spi 774e0645 key 16:DAC0A7B14F20741D20112FA78EFB607A auth 20:17D48DCACA549180D9D88F6F1A491AD35F26A8D4
    Line 1525: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: IPsec SA enc spi e1bb6929 key 16:A07004A6732F20FE413AD2BCABC1BCA7 auth 20:02B237443000C49D76FCAC2BC0F3A6ED88FF3EF6
    Line 1525: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: IPsec SA enc spi e1bb6929 key 16:A07004A6732F20FE413AD2BCABC1BCA7 auth 20:02B237443000C49D76FCAC2BC0F3A6ED88FF3EF6
    Line 1526: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: added IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0645/e1bb6929
    Line 1526: ike 0:Brazil_VPN:2803378:Brazil_ph2:19810263: added IPsec SA: SPIs=774e0645/e1bb6929
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the VPN policy or route/interface based?  Can you update the original question with applicable policies?

Comment: Missing routes? There is way too little information in your post.